# Ckeditor not clearing up for on submit in angular

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a form in angular. In one of the field I use, ckeditor. (ckeditor4angular)

Ckeditor text area does not clears up, even when the angular form is reset.

I tired updating it with 2 way binding but that did not work.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.